Aligning images in flexbox (works with background-image, but not with <img/>)
How can I achieve the same alignment with <img/> as I do with background-image?

Link to sandbox
The two bottles in the upper right corner are aligned the way I want:

Fill the height
Get clipped to fit the width
Don't overflow

They're not <img/> elements, but divs with background-image.
The problem: The two bottles in the lower right corner use <img/> elements (which is what I want), but they don't behave the same.
I can of course set the width of the images explicitly (like 50%), but the images might be different sizes, or there might be more of them. Therefore I'd like to avoid explicitly setting the width.
How can I fix this?
Never mind the image on the left.
Here's the code:


.app {
  padding: 5%;
}
.app > * {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 18px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 18px;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-position: center !important;
}
.box.column {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.box.hasBackground {
  padding: 5%;
}
.box img {
  object-fit: cover;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
<div class="app">
  <div class="box row hasBackground" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(250, 208, 196) 0%, rgb(255, 209, 255) 100%);">
    <div class="box row ">
      <img src="https://velgnorsk.no/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Ocean-bottle_VN_marinebla%CC%8A.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="box column ">
      <div class="box row ">
        <div class="box row hasBackground" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://velgnorsk.no/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Ocean-bottle_VN_marinebla%CC%8A.jpg&quot;);"></div>
        <div class="box row hasBackground" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://velgnorsk.no/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Ocean-bottle_VN_marinebla%CC%8A.jpg&quot;);"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box row ">
        <img src="https://velgnorsk.no/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Ocean-bottle_VN_marinebla%CC%8A.jpg">
        <img src="https://velgnorsk.no/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Ocean-bottle_VN_marinebla%CC%8A.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Added code now

Your div elements in the top row have flex: 1, so that they know to divide the available space between them evenly. But your images in the bottom row don't have that, so how is their width supposed to be determined ...? Add flex:1; width: 50%

Good point, but not what I'm looking for. I the pictures might be different sizes, or there might be more of them. Thus I'd like to not set the width like that. I've updated the description now.

"Fill the height" - where is the overall height that is to fill here, supposed to come from? Are you setting it somewhere?



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .background-container {
            background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(250, 208, 196) 0%, rgb(255, 209, 255) 100%);
            display: flex;
        }

        .left-image {
            width: 50%;
            padding: 30px;
        }

        .right-images {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .row1,
        .row2 {
            display: flex;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 30px;
        }


        .left-image img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: 15px;
        }

        .right-images img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: 15px;
        }

        .row1-image2, .row2-image2{
            margin-left: 15px;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="app">
        <div class="background-container">
            <div class="left-image">
                <img src="https://velgnorsk.no/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Ocean-bottle_VN_marinebla%CC%8A.jpg"
                    alt="image">
            </div>
            <div class="right-images">
                <div class="row1">
                    <div class="row1-image1">
                        <img src="https://velgnorsk.no/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Ocean-bottle_VN_marinebla%CC%8A.jpg"
                            alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row1-image2">
                        <img src="https://velgnorsk.no/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Ocean-bottle_VN_marinebla%CC%8A.jpg"
                            alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row2">
                    <div class="row2-image1">
                        <img src="https://velgnorsk.no/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Ocean-bottle_VN_marinebla%CC%8A.jpg"
                            alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row2-image2">
                        <img src="https://velgnorsk.no/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Ocean-bottle_VN_marinebla%CC%8A.jpg"
                            alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>

</html>



Your class name looks too confusing for me so I did it on my own.
I did not use any hard values and also I did not use background image. I use Flexbox to replicate your layout. But it is more convenient to use grid in this kind of layout.
here the gap looks too much but when you open it on the large screen it seems to be just what you want
